# ImportError: No module named bootstrap3

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I installed bootstrap3 with

```
$ pip install django-bootstrap3
```

It is being installed in this directory

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/
```

Django seems to be looking at this directory

```
/Users/shawnpike/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/
```

When I put 'bootstrap3' in the INSTALLED_APPS = ('bootstrap3') variable and then run

```
$ python manage.py runserver
```

I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/shawnpike/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/shawnpike/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/shawnpike/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/shawnpike/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/Users/shawnpike/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 87, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/Users/shawnpike/anaconda/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
ImportError: No module named bootstrap3
```

I installed bootstrap3 in the django folder by using copy and paste and that did not work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You!

Comment: in the django shell, can you import bootstrap3 successfully ?

Comment: no I get                                                                   '---------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                       
ImportError                                                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-0f2210d3f3fa> in <module>()
----> 1 import bootstrap3

ImportError: No module named bootstrap3'

Comment: LOoks like you have 2 installations of python. Would highly encourage you to use virtualenvironments. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv That way, the installation would point to the current version of python

Answer (score 10):

Just see which python version your Django environment is using with:

```
python -V
```

If it is using `Python 2.7` run:

```
pip install django-bootstrap3
```

Otherwise, if your Django environment is using version `Python 3` use:

```
pip3 install django-bootstrap3
```

Answer (score 5):

Try using

```
$pip2 install django-bootstrap3
```

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 and and the pip command installs packages to lib/python3.3/site-packages/ and not to lib/python2.7/site-packages/

Answer (score 2):

You have to install Requirements.txt and it will be ok.

Run this command:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: This assumes the necessary packages have already been specified in the requirements.txt file, and that the file is present, otherwise this wouldn't fix his issue I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
pip install django-bootstrap3
```

Instead of:

```
pip3 install django-bootstrap3
```

I found out even using just plain old pip just works (even in a python3 environment )when you're using a virtual environment (I was using anaconda). For some reason pip3 doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If Using Conda Virtual Environment First, check **conda list**

If django-bootstrap3 is not there then install using **python -m pip install django-bootstrap3**

After this try migrating once again.

**I hope this solution works!**