# Error starting the server?

Tags: django-bootstrap3

I use PyCharm and when I try to run the server I get this error. My OS is Windows x64.

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.
<locals>.wrapper at 0x0000025D31464598>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.1-py3.6.egg\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.1-py3.6.egg\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.1-py3.6.egg\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 250, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.1-py3.6.egg\django\utils\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.1-py3.6.egg\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.1-py3.6.egg\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.1-py3.6.egg\django\apps\registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.1-py3.6.egg\django\apps\config.py", line 94, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 948, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bootstrap3'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the package boostrap3 with pip3 (I think you have Python3).

> pip3 install django-bootstrap3

Source: [ImportError: No module named bootstrap3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25941413/importerror-no-module-named-bootstrap3)

Comment: Please use:
python -m pip3
to run this feature
or:
python PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR\Scripts\pip3-script.py

Comment: You will need to configure pip on windows so, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41501636/how-to-install-pip3-on-windows/41501815#41501815

Comment: Not helped. Thanks!